# Frequency-Dependant Light Transmission In One Direction

Tags: optics, material-science

Is it physically possible to have a material that transmits only transmits light above a certain frequency in one direction and transmits frequencies below that frequency in the opposite direction.  I assume not, but I'm curious if there is a fundamental reason why that isn't possible in theory.

Comment: Related: [Layer of material that transmits light in one direction and absorbs it in the other direction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/497471)

Answer (score 1):

Time reversal invariance?  If light  goes the left, then the time reversed photons go to the right with the same frequency.

Comment: Nothing to do with time reversal invariance but with a non-reciprocal magnetic device such as a Faraday rotator one can build circulators. If you add low pass/high pass filters in the output arms it might even emulate what the OP is asking for, but am not sure about that.

Comment: @hyportnex - but that then is an optical system, not the optical properties of one material.